# Yii2. Валидация полей модели по условию ИЛИ

Tags: yii2, form, валидация

Есть обычная модель для формы обратной связи.

Поля: name, phone, email, body

Можно ли сделать проверку полей по условию:
Обязательно заполнено поле телефон ИЛИ почта.

Т.е. одно из них обязательно заполнено и корректно.
Средствами самого Yii2 без своего js.

Насколько я понял - сценарии немного для другого. rules() тоже не могу понять как применить для моего случая

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `when` и `whenClient`, но если оба поля будут не заполнены, то и подсвечиваться как обязательные к заполнению будут оба поля:

```
public function rules()
{
    ['field_1', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->field_2 == '';
    }, 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
        return $("#field_2").val() == "";
    }', 'message' => 'Заполните field 1 либо field 2'],

    ['field_2', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->field_1 == '';
    }, 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
        return $("#field_1").val() == "";
    }', 'message' => 'Заполните field 1 либо field 2']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['phone', 'email'], 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return (!$model->phone && !$model->email);
        },'whenClient' => 'function(){return false;}',
        /*'whenClient' => 'function (attr, value) {
            return $("#MODEL-phone").val() == "" && $("#MODEL-email").val() == "";
        }', 'message' => 'Заполните phone или email'*/],
        //...
    ];
}
```

Дополнительно можно описать `whenClient` и `message`